# why SurfaceView is not deprecated?

Tags: android, surfaceview, textureview

i know that TextureView is show up after ICS.
but, SurfaceView is not deprecated at ICS.

SurfaceView has hole-punching structure, so it has many limit point.
can't stack two SurfaceView and can't translate and etc..

why SurfaceView is not deprecated despite of TextureView is show up?

Answer (score 5):

SurfaceView is faster, and can handle DRM-protected video.

The hole-punching structure is necessary because SurfaceView's Surface is handled directly by the system compositor.  For TextureView, you draw on a Surface, which is converted to a GL texture within the app, which is rendered a second time by the app onto the View layer.  So there's an extra copy.

For DRM-protected video, no user or system code -- not even the Linux kernel -- is allowed to see unencrypted pixels.  Only the video decoder and the display hardware.  Because SurfaceView just forwards references through, and doesn't touch the actual data, this works.

For more details, see the [graphics architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: Thank you for detailed explain.
simplify, Because of SurfaceView is handle data directly (there's no copy), SurfaceView is need for DRM or lightweight handling.

then, why there's no option for 'copy' or 'direct draw' ?
is it hard to combine of two component?

I mean something like flag options.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The two classes fulfill different roles -- one for in-app rendering with a lot of control but a small performance hit, the other streamlined but with limited control. It sounds like you want something halfway between?